# How to replace string in a file text based on regex?

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7

Assume:

```
self.base_version = 1000
self.target_version = 2000
```

I have a file as follows:

```
some text...
<tsr_args> \"upgrade_test test_mode=upgrade       base_sw=1000      target_sw=2000      system_profile=eth\"</tsr_args>

some text...

<tsr_args> \"upgrade_test test_mode=rollback      base_sw=2000      target_sw=1000      system_profile=eth      manufacture_type=no-manufacture\"</tsr_args>

some text...

<tsr_args> \"upgrade_test test_mode=downgrade     base_sw=2000      target_sw=1000      system_profile=eth      no_boot_next_enable_flag=True\"</tsr_args>
```

I need the base and target version values to be placed as specified above (Note that on the 2nd and 3rd entry, the base and target are opposite).

I tried to do it as follows, but it does not work:

```
base_regex   = re.compile('.*test_mode.*base_sw=(.*)')
target_regex = re.compile('.*test_mode.*target_sw=(.*)')

o = open(file,'a')

for line in open(file):
    if      'test_mode' in line:
        if     'upgrade' in line:
                new_line = (re.sub(base_regex, self.base_version, line))
                new_line = (re.sub(target_regex, self.target_version, line))
                o.write(new_line)

        elif   'rollback' in line or 'downgrade' in line):
               new_line = (re.sub(base_regex, self.target_version, line))
               new_line = (re.sub(target_regex, self.base_version, line))
               o.write(new_line)
o.close()
```

Assume the above code runs properly without any syntax errors.

1. The file is not modified at all.
2. The complete line is modified instead of just the captured group. How can I make re.sub to substitute only the captured group?

Comment: I tried running your code and got `SyntaxError: invalid syntax`. Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: I can`t share the whole code. Assume the above runs without any syntax error. Does o.write() OVERWRITES the current line or does it ADD a new line?

Comment: instead of (.*), use (\d*) if its always going to be numbers or (\S*) for non whitespace. (.*) means any character except for new line.

Comment: How can I make re.sub to substitute only the captured group?

Comment: Thankss for the "\S*". I modified the code accordingly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You are opening file with `a` -> `append`. So, your changes should be at the end of file. You should create a new file and replace old_one at the end of your script.
2. There is only one way I know if you want replace several matching groups: first of all you find word using regexp and replace it like a string without regexp.

Comment: What should I do in order to OVERWRITE the existing line which I currently replace? should I open it with "w"?

Comment: How can I make re.sub to substitute only the captured group?

Comment: @Qwerty, `re.sub` substitute only group. I think your regexp could be too broad.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Jimilan for your remarks. I fixed my code, and now it`s working:

```
        base_regex   = re.compile(.*test_mode.*base_sw=(\S*))
        target_regex = re.compile(.*test_mode.*target_sw=(\S*))

        for file in self.upgrade_cases_files_list:

            file_handle = open(file, 'r')
            file_string = file_handle.read()
            file_handle.close()

            base_version_result   = base_regex.search(file_string)
            target_version_result = target_regex.search(file_string)

            if base_version_result is not None:
                current_base_version = base_version_result.group(1)
            else:
                raise Exception("Could not detect base version in the following file: -> %s \n" % (file))

            if target_version_result is not None:
                current_target_version = target_version_result.group(1)
            else:
                raise Exception("Could not detect target version in the following file: -> %s \n" % (file))

            file_string = file_string.replace(current_base_version, self.base_version)
            file_string = file_string.replace(current_target_version, self.target_version)

            file_handle = open(file, 'w')
            file_handle.write(file_string)
            file_handle.close()
```